# missing `@` on instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Ruby class with an initialize method:

```
def initialize(params)
  @foo = private_method(params || {})
end
```

Later in the same class, I see the following:

```
def new_method_for(user)
  foo.each { |f| other_method(f) }
end
```

Why is the `@` missing from in front of foo in `other_method`? When I put a binding.pry in before `foo.each...`, both foo and @foo are defined.

Comment: Your class probably has a getter defined for `@foo`. That is, either using an accessor definition (`:attr_reader foo` or `:attr_accessor foo`) or explicit `def foo` instance method, `foo` is probably defined as a getter. You're not showing all the code, so hard to tell.

Comment: Because it's an `attr_accessor` or `attr_reader` and there's a `foo` getter method.

Comment: Yes, there is a line `attr_reader :foo`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the class that contains the `new_method_for(user)` method, you should see an `attr_reader`, `attr_writer` or both represented by `attr_accessor`

So it should look like this:

```
class SomeClass
 attr_accessor :foo

end
```